# Angular 1.x nested parent directive - how to isolate them?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I don't think I understand how to ask this question to Google, though I have tried.

Imagine this structure in pseudocode:

```
<div parent-directive="bar">
  <input child-directive="foo" />
  <div parent-directive="baz">
    <input child-directive="bazzbazz" />
  </div>
</div>
```

`child-directive` needs to communicate with its immediate `parent-directive`. So I use `require: ['^parentDirective']` which works except when I have a nested `parent-directive` (ie: baz). Now all children are pointing to the "baz" `parent-directive`.
I'd like bazzbazz (child) to talk to baz (parent) and foo (child) to talk to bar (parent).

How can this be accomplished in Angular 1.x?

PS I am limited to Angular 1.2.x, so any solution that can take that into account would be great.

Here is an example of how this might be implemented (incorrectly) using "forms" as a parent and "input fields" as a child:

```
app.directive('myform', function() {
  const directive = {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) { /*...*/ },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      this.sendMessage = function() { console.log('Got message from child') }
    }
  }
})
app.directive('myfield', function() {
    return {
      require: ['^myform'],
      link: function (scope, elem, attr, parentDirective) {
        parentDirective.sendMessage('Hi!')
      }
    }
})
```

and in html

```
<div myform="foo">
  <!-- I want bar to send messages to foo, but not baz -->
  <input myfield="bar" />
  <div myform="baz" />
</div>
```

when I tried in a much larger codebase/scenario, I found that "bar" was getting a reference to "baz".

Comment: `require` can't do that. Explaining why exactly you do that would help to find a proper alternative solution. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @estus thanks for the reply. Perhaps there's a better way to phrase my question - but as I wrote, I want a child directive (ie: foo) to get a reference to / send messages to a parent directive (ie: bar) without sibling directives of the same type as the parent (ie: baz) getting the message. Does that help?

Comment: This means that interaction should be performed the other way rather than `require` (scope events or service or directive refactoring) but doesn't explain anything. Please, provide working example that reflects your case. It matters what these directives really are and how comes that they have this hierarchy with these types.

Comment: @estus Okay, for example say I have a "form" directive as a parent and a "field" directive as a child. I want to be able to embed "forms" within "forms". Messages to and from "forms" and their immediate child "field" should not be caught by other "form" directives.

Comment: You can use event namespaces, like `$rootScope.$broadcast('forms:foo', ...)` which will be received only by 'foo' items - or `$scope.$emit('forms:foo', ...)` if it's emitted from a child to a parent. Relying on global events can hardly be called a good design but this will work. I can't suggest anything more specific and useful without seeing the code.

Comment: @estus as I can't paste directly from the project :) I added some sample code, is that enough or do I need something like plunker? I think you've answered the question except that will $broadcast be received by sibling foos or just parent foos? Because what I want is just parent foos.

Comment: @estus oh... does the broadcast "forms:foo" only send to "forms" directives with "foo" as the attribute? The value of the attribute for "foo" isn't known by the children in my example. Appreciate your efforts to answer.

Comment: Sorry, the examples are too vague to figure out how this should be properly refactored. It *really* depends on what's going on in these directives. $rootScope.$broadcast (not $scope.$broadcast) will be received by everyone and thus will do the job, but it can be considered antipattern (this is global scope, but for events). `forms:foo` will be received everywhere where you do `$scope.$on('forms:foo', ...)`. Is there a way for 'foo' directives to know that they are 'foo'? If there's none, you should clearly provide a namespace variable for them - through attribute or whatever.